# chart is not showing from JSON data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, datatable

Actually i want to show chart by using JSON data.When i entered the url the JSON data is coming but it is not showing in chart form.I am not getting any error in console.

[image: This is the image of my JSON data coming]

try.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<title></title>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript">

      var dataPoints = [];
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/FRA-UI/api/report19graph/all", function(data) {  
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
              dataPoints.push({x: value[0], y: value[1]});
          });
          var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
              title:{
                  text:"Rendering Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
              },
              data: [{
              type: "line",
                  dataPoints : dataPoints,
              }]
          });
          chart.render();
      });

  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>


</body>
</html>
```

restwebcontroller.java

```
@GetMapping(value="/report19graph/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Report19Graph> getReport19GraphData(){
        List<Report19Graph> list=reportService.getReport19GraphData();
        return list;

    }
```

Comment: add # in your code here new CanvasJS.Chart("#chartContainer",{

Comment: and place your custom jquery code below canvajs script

Comment: No bro it is not working i tried as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think there are a couple of issues with your code. First, I created an object similar to the screenshot you posted of your data:

```
let data = [{
  "rangeLab": "10-15",
  "rangeVal": 220.763
}, {
  "rangeLab": "15-20",
  "rangeVal": 128.554
}, {
  "rangeLab": "20-25",
  "rangeVal": 150
}];
```

To get this in the format you want, I looped over each object in the array, and specified "x" to be the value of the first object and "y" to be the value of the second object:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  dataPoints.push({
    x: value[Object.keys(value)[0]],
    y: value[Object.keys(value)[1]]
  });
});
```

That gave me the `dataPoints` object in the correct format expected by CanvasJS:

```
[{"x":"10-15","y":220.763},{"x":"15-20","y":128.554},{"x":"20-25","y":150}]
```

The next issue is that CanvasJS seems to expect a `Number` for values of `x` and `y`. To do what you want, I think you need to use the `label` property. So I changed the loop code to:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  dataPoints.push({
    label: value[Object.keys(value)[0]],
    y: value[Object.keys(value)[1]]
  });
});
```

And then it seemed to render correctly.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nzr5ds12/10/

Comment: What is showing in your console for `dataPoints` (i.e., `console.log(dataPoints)`? Also, the example in the JSFiddle I linked to works. Other than the AJAX call, is there anything different between your code and my JSFiddle?

Comment: when i did it the datas are pushed in dataPoints array . but still the chart is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[x-value](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/) can be numeric or a dateTime value and can't be string. As [@androidnoobie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927172/androidnoobie) suggested you can consider rangeLab as [label](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/).

Also I would suggest you to create chart once, outside the AJAX request, and just update dataPoints within AJAX. Else, it creates new chart on every AJAX request. Please refer [Tutorial on Charts from JSON Data API and AJAX](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/javascript-charts-from-json-data-api-and-ajax/).

```
var dataPoints = [];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title:{
        text:"Rendering Chart with dataPoints from External JSON"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        dataPoints : dataPoints,
    }]
});
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/FRA-UI/api/report19graph/all", function(data) {  
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        dataPoints.push({x: value[0], y: value[1]});
    });
    chart.render();
});
```